# Deleting shapefile python (lock?) (QGIS 3.10)

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, shapefile, pyqgis-3

I have trouble with deleting shapefiles and notice a weird behavior when I am running my scripts
(Version QGIS 3.14.15-Pi)

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
path_layer = layer.source()
cloned_layer = clone_vl(layer) # makes a memory layer and copies crs, features, attributes, ...
QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(layer.id())
del layer
print(QgsVectorFileWriter.deleteShapeFile(path_layer))
```

returns False if I run it as a script inside the Python console editor of QGIS
but return True if I execute it line after line directly in the console.

Which seems like something weird is going on, like if I execute the script, QGIS doesn't have the 'time' to unlock the shapefile or something.

What is going on?

Comment: Have you tried with the [QgsVectorFileWriter class](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorFileWriter.html?highlight=qgsvectorfile#module-QgsVectorFileWriter) ?

Comment: @J.Monticolo Thx i hadn't even noticed QgsVectorFile doesn't exist, i was trying with QgsVectorFileWriter

Comment: I just tested your script in a QGIS console editor without the `cloned_layer` script line (because I don't have the function) on QGIS 3.14 on Ubuntu 20.04 and it returns `True`.